# Duplication of left-side links in review

Tags: bug, review-system

I'm getting a weird bug when trying to review one question: https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-posts/127819

The left side links (including the MO banner) are duplicating, and the question itself is further indented. The duplicated links in the banner and text work. I reviewed other questions before this, and the problem didn't show up there, though this is the first question in the "First Posts" queue. The below is a screenshot taken by the browser (hence the weird position of the top bar). 
[image: Image of bug]

Edited to add: I'm now getting it in another "First Posts" post, https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-posts/127829 , as well as the same question in the "Late Answers" queue. Additionally, the "Skip" button seems to never load the next question. Further, after doing so, the Review queues dropdown doesn't work, instead acting as a link. The "Skip" does register, however - the queues are empty afterwards. The "Review" queue seems to load normally.

Edit 3/27/2020: The problem has returned; I am currently seeing it while reviewing https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-posts/128082

Comment: It seems that some other users had problems with review queues today, too: [Low Quality Post review is unreadable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345341) and [I am experiencing difficulty in the rendering of posts in the “review first posts queue.”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31361)